# NSMutableDictionary & multiple thread access

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've a NSMutableDictionary , that i add to some custom NSObjects which i receive asynchronously. Each time i receive new  data i clear the dictionary then add the new objects. Then push data to another class "UIView" to render the content in the dictionary. I have been getting SIGABRT exception which as far as i know means the object trying to access has been released. I have tried synchronization blocks ,  creating a mututablecopy and getting allvalues but nothing worked now My question how i can achieve synchronization

here is a code snippet ,

```
@interface MyAltViewController : UIViewController
{
   __block NSMutableDictionary *currentDataList;
    TestUIVIEW *myUIVIEW
}
@implementation MyAltViewController

......
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   currentDataList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(processDataMessag:)
                                         name:view_Data object:nil];
}
.....
-(void)processDataMessag:(NSNotification *) notification
{
  [currentDataList removeAllObjects];
  NSArray tmpAr= (NSArray*) [notification object]
  dispatch_async(dbQueue, ^(void)
  {
     /// Loop through the array and process the data then add to NSDictionary 

     [self pushtoMUViewLayer:currentDataList];
  });

}
.........
 -(void)pushtoMUViewLayer:(NSMutableDictionary *)ina
 {
     /// Even here if i try to access and object within 
     /// currentDataList and just a specific NSString i get the SIGABRT
    [myUIVIEW updateWithData:ina];
 }
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////
 @interface TestUIVIEW : UIView
 {
    NSMutableDictionary *mdata;
    UIImage *outputImage ;

 }
 @property (assign) NSMutableDictionary *mapdata;
 @property (retain) UIImage *outputImage ;

  @implementation TestUIVIEW
    .......
  -(void)updateWithData:(NSMutableDictionary *)data
  {
     mdata = [data retain]; // ??? not  sure how to set it correctly
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
      { 
        [self CreateImage];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
      });
  }
  -(void) CreateImage
  {
    NSString *key;
    for(key  in mapdata)
    {
        DataMessage *tmpData= (DataMessage*)[mapdata objectForKey:key];
        NSString *aID = [ tmpData alt] ;
        double aLat   = [ tmpData lat]  ;
        double aLong  = [ tmpData lon] ;
       /*
          Drawing code  I can Get aLat & A Long
          but it fails with SiABRT when trying to render 
          aID
       /*
    }
  }

  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
  {
    // Drawing code

   CGPoint imagePoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);

   [outputImage drawAtPoint:imagePoint];

}
```

/// if that synchronization didnt work . i can use NSNotification to see my currentDataList
   // to my currentDataList

Comment: Show your code, we aren't wizards.

Comment: It seems like you're on the right track to solve this yourself. How are you receiving the data, through notifications perhaps? One way to make debugging this easier is to log every dealloc with information about the objecting being deallocated. This should at least help you see if anything is deallocated unexpectedly to you...

Comment: Have you tried `@synchronize` around all the places that modify or access the array?  (Use the NSMutableArray itself as the synchronized object.)

Comment: I added @synchronised block around all the places where i access the NSDictionary.  I can print out all the fields in each object that i extract from the dictionary . When i try [[myobjectInDic alt] UTF8String] i get that SIGABRT exception but if i just simply printed out to the screen it works

Comment: We have no idea what `[myobjectInDic alt]` is.

Answer (score 1):

Adding @synchronised block around all the places where i access the NSDictionary did solove the problem . Thanks all for your input